# Why can invoked functions be prefixed with a name + colon in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I found this code snippet in some very old JS code (simplified to a working example):

```
foo:console.log('I have a prefix')
```

This works and logs as you would expect. What is going on here? I initially thought this would be a syntax error. (note that the original form I discovered this in was as `javascript:foo()`).

Comment: Javascript has labels.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a lable statement, not very common feature. But sometimes you can see them in nested loops for example, to name loop in order to reference it later to break it or continue.

Of course in your example with `console.log` it's totally useless and confusing.

Reference: [Labeled statements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label).

Comment: didnt now that this feature exists. Nice answer.

Comment: Yes, because the only practical application for them is loops, but even there they are used rarely.

Comment: Ah of course - I have used labels myself of course - but I was totally thrown by seeing them in such a bizarre context. Great answer.